# Checkbox doesn't work in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have small form with checkbox. When I fill the form and save data to database and try to fill it with another data to save it to database my checkbox doesn't work. It works only when I refresh page. here is code.

```
<form action="javascript:saveNewBreakfast();" name="basic_validate"
            id="breakfast_validate" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="control-group" id="add_breakfast" style="display: none">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Select new one</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <select name="required" id="breakfast_select">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input
                        id="is_free_breakfast" type="checkbox" checked>Is
                        free ? </label>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group" id="price_breakfast" style="display: none">
                    <label class="control-label">Price</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="number" min="0"
                            style="border-radius: 5pc; height: 30px; width: 280px; margin-bottom: 0px;"
                             id="breakfast_price"> EUR
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini; btn-success">Save</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>


$('#is_free_breakfast').change(function(){
    getIsFree = $('#is_free_breakfast').is(':checked');
    if(getIsFree){
        $('#price_breakfast').hide();
    }else{
        $('#price_breakfast').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: "Does not work" means what exactly?

Comment: @Hajrudin : Show and Hide not working on checkbox value change?

Comment: @user3154108  Second time when I want to add new breakfast I can't click on checkbox. Like it is disabled.

Comment: @Thulasiram Nothing happened when I click on checkbox. Even checkbox want check or uncheck.

Comment: @Hajrudin when I use your code, the checkbox works just fine. Maybe you have another element laying ontop of your checkbox when you want to check it the second time?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to explicit `reset` the form if you are using js handler for form submit (`action=""`).

Something like:

```
function saveNewBreakfast() {
    // submit handler code

    // reset the form to initial values
    $('#breakfast_validate')[0].reset();

    // show/hide the input based on checkbox's initial values
    $('#is_free_breakfast').change();
}
```

**NOTE:** `reset` is a HTML DOM Element method (i.e. plain js function), and not 
a jQuery one, so `$('selector')[0]` is used to convert jquery object to DOM element. Or you can use plain js

```
document.getElementById('breakfast_validate').reset();
```

---

Here's a demo:

```js
function saveNewBreakfast() {
  // submit hanlder code

  alert('saved with price: ' + ($('#breakfast_price').val() || 'free'));

  $('#breakfast_validate')[0].reset();
  $('#is_free_breakfast').change();
}

$('#is_free_breakfast').change(function() {
  getIsFree = $('#is_free_breakfast').is(':checked');
  if (getIsFree) {
    $('#price_breakfast').hide();
  } else {
    $('#price_breakfast').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="javascript:saveNewBreakfast();" name="basic_validate" id="breakfast_validate" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="control-group" id="add_breakfast">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Select new one</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select name="required" id="breakfast_select">
                        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="checkbox-inline"><input
                        id="is_free_breakfast" type="checkbox" checked>Is
                        free ? </label>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" id="price_breakfast" style="display: none">
      <label class="control-label">Price</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="number" min="0" style="border-radius: 5pc; height: 30px; width: 280px; margin-bottom: 0px;" id="breakfast_price"> EUR
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini; btn-success">Save</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var html_content = '<label class="control-label">Price</label>' +
                       '<div class="controls">' +
                           '<input type="number" min="0"' +
                             'style="border-radius: 5pc; height: 30px; width: 280px; margin-bottom: 0px;"' +
                             'name="breakfast_price" id="breakfast_price"> EUR' +
                       '</div> ';


    $('#is_free_breakfast').change(function () {
        getIsFree = $('#is_free_breakfast').is(':checked');
        if (getIsFree) {
            $('#price_breakfast').empty();
        } else {
            $('#price_breakfast').html(html_content);
        }
    });

});

function form_submit(){
  var queryString = $('#breakfast_validate').serialize();
  console.log(queryString);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="javascript:saveNewBreakfast();" name="basic_validate"
    id="breakfast_validate" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="control-group" id="add_breakfast">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Select new one</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select name="required" id="breakfast_select">
                    <option>option 1</option>
                    <option>option 2</option>
                    <option>option 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input
                    id="is_free_breakfast" type="checkbox" checked>Is free ?
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" id="price_breakfast">
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <button type="button" onclick="form_submit()" class="btn btn-mini; btn-success">Save</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```